# Install Citra-Emulator Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: software-installation, 17.04, executable, emulation

I'm trying to install [Citra Emulator](https://citra-emu.org). I downloaded and extracted it (tar.xz) and it gives me an "executable (application/x-executable)". When I try to run it, nothing happens. I've also tried running it from terminal with

```
./citra
```

I`m running Ubuntu 17.04, let me know if any more information is needed.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the executable has the correct permissions. If not, run `chmod +x ./citra` and `chmod 776` or similar. Then, try to execute it with `./citra` or `sh ./citra`.

If this doesn't work, try looking if it has some missing dependencies with:

`ldd ./citra`

For the error mentioned:

Try looking at: [libsdl2-2-0-so-0-cannot-open-shared-object-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29711336/libsdl2-2-0-so-0-cannot-open-shared-object-file)

Or

[sdl2-not-being-loaded-correctly-by-jedi-academy-openjk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/444732/sdl2-not-being-loaded-correctly-by-jedi-academy-openjk)

Answer (score 1):

You can Download The "citra-setup-linux" from the site and run it using

```
chmod +x ./citra-setup-linux
```

And Then

```
./citra-setup-linux
```

Answer (score -1):

I am on Ubuntu 18.04 and I can confirm https://citra-emu.org/wiki/building-for-ubuntu-16.04/ is working for me.

However, before step 2, I had to do the following:

```
sudo rm /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libEGL.so
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libEGL.so.1.1.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libEGL.so
sudo rm /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.7.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so
```